# How to create a index file in java

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what is the use of -1 here? cant understand why it has to be there

```
public void indexFile(File file) throws IOException {
        int fileno = files.indexOf(file.getPath());
        if (fileno == -1) {
            files.add(file.getPath());
            fileno = files.size() - 1;
        }
```

Comment: What is `files`?  A string?

Comment: I think its a StringBuffer

Comment: List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: I posted an answer below. If it helped, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the white checkmark underneath the score. Thank you.

Comment: @CardingSungkit Consider looking at [the documentation...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: thank you for all suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the `-1` means that the string `file.getPath()` does not exist in the list `files`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is going on because I don't know what "files" stands for...

However, I think I can hazard a guess based on naming conventions.

This method does not create an index file. It indexes a given file in a `List<String>` called `files`. The `files` object is a combination of all the previous files. If the file is in the buffer, `fileno!=-1`, if `fileno==-1`, then it adds the path to the buffer and sets the index to its new point.